# knockout not recognizing changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an interesting error going on in my code that is quite frankly stumping me.

In our app we have an onscreen keyboard for touch screen users and we are using knockout to observe those inputs and update what to pass to the database. To trigger the observable fields we put in a `trigger('change')` since the keyboard just stuffs the value in the input field.

And this was seemingly working, however it is becoming apparent that this is only working about half the time. The `trigger('change')` seems to be firing, but the knockout just is not recognizing it as a change.

The trigger looks like this

```
var updatedValue = characterKey;
this.currentElement.val(updatedValue).trigger('change');
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I sympathize with your situation, but without a repro, we can only guess at the problem, let alone the solutions.

Comment: See @Jeroen comment. It looks like you are directly manipulating html elements rather than using knockout directly, but without more code it's hard to say